# Multiple checkbox function PHP & Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, function, checkbox

I'm a beginner in both PHP & MySql and I 've been working with the multiple checkboxes function for days. At first nothing seem to to work but nonetheless, it has finally given the result but I can't seem to create a table out of it

And here is the php page:

```
<?php


if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{       
    $str = ' 1=1 ';     

    if( count($_POST['field']) > 0 )
    {       
        $field =  implode(',',$_POST['field']);     
        $str.= ' AND company_field LIKE '.$field.'';
    }

    if( count($_POST['size']) > 0 )
    {           
        $size =  implode(',',$_POST['size']); 
        $str.= ' AND company_size LIKE '.$size.'';
    }

    $run = "SELECT * FROM company WHERE 1=1 AND company_field LIKE '$field' AND company_size LIKE '$size'";
    echo $run;
    $result = mysql_query($run);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $company_name = $row[0];
    $company_field = $row[1];
    $company_size = $row[2];

?>
<tr align = 'center'>
<th><?php echo $company_name; ?></th>
<td><?php echo $company_field; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $company_size; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
<?php } ?>
```

But I can't create a table and I don't know why.

Comment: sidenote: since you're new to php and mysql, avoid the habit of using deprecated functions, avoid using `msql_` functions, use the improved one `mysqli_` and use prepared statements. [link](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should)

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look through it.

Comment: I don't understand the logic of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly create a table you need the `<table>` tags like so:

```
<table>
    <tr align = 'center'>
        <th><?php echo $company_name; ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $company_field; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $company_size; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you're making a new row in your "while" you should put the `<table>` tag BEFORE your loop and the `</table>` tag AFTER your loop

Comment: _The align attribute of <table> is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead._